# Data Transformation

Tags: sql, oracle, transformation

I have following Data in a table

```
ID      Field1     Field2    Field3
1       A
1                  B
1                            C
2                  D
2                            E
2       F
1       G
1       H
```

I would like to transform it in following

```
ID      Field1     Field2    Field3
1       A          B         C
1       G
1       H
2       F          D         E
```

Is this something which can be done using SQL or I have to go on PL/SQL?
The data I expect here would be in millions, hence I would like to give CROSS JOIN a pass.

Comment: Do you have a primary key on that table? Do you want to modify the data on the table (so Update + Delete) or to simply Select it?

Comment: @ASolvent: Why are B and C to be returned on the same row as A, but not G or H? Is there another column (not displayed) that determines this?

Comment: OMG- I had similar situation before but then the Data was 100(s) so I sent the data to the front end and manipulated it there with ease. I can do it with cursors.

Comment: @xanatos- I don't have a primary key but can add an auto number on the fly. A select will be the best, if not possible then probably I have to use delete/update.

Comment: @Mark: B & C are dependent on ID. if you see the transformed table, you will find that data is arranged on the basis of ID.

Comment: @ASolvent: If you see either the original table or the transformed table, you will find that G and H have the same ID as A. So why do B and C appear next to A, but not G or H?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following select statement to aggregate some of the rows.

```
select ID, min(Field1) Field1, min(Field2) Field2, min(Field3) Field3
    from your_table
    group by ID
    -- Ignore rows where this would lose data
    having nvl(count(Field1),0) < 2
       and nvl(count(Field2),0) < 2
       and nvl(count(Field3),0) < 2
```

When I run that on your test data, I get the following result.

```
   ID FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3
----- ------ ------ ------
    2 F      D      E
```

You could loop through this in PL/SQL, delete all rows with the ID, and insert one row with this data.

Maybe you could use the first_value function for a second pass.

My instinct suggests that this table might not be properly normalized.  Maybe you should have a separate table.  It would look like the result of this query:

```
select id, 'Field1' field_id, Field1 field_value
    from your_table
    where field1 is not null
union
select id, 'Field2' field_id, Field2 field_value
    from your_table
    where field2 is not null
union
select id, 'Field3' field_id, Field3 field_value
    from your_table
    where field3 is not null
order by 1, 2, 3
/

  ID FIELD_ F
---- ------ -
   1 Field1 A
   1 Field1 G
   1 Field1 H
   1 Field2 B
   1 Field3 C
   2 Field1 F
   2 Field2 D
   2 Field3 E
```

If you can't renormalize your table, you could try to loop through the same (normalization) query within PL/SQL.  You would have a stack for each field and push the values for each row.  When the ID changes, you would then create rows by popping fields 1, 2, and 3 from each of the stacks, filling in with nulls, and repeating until all three stacks are exhausted.

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting problem. You're not the first one. See the last 7 pages here (no solution for your problem but maybe interesting):
http://wwwlgis.informatik.uni-kl.de/cms/fileadmin/courses/ws1112/Middleware/Vorlesung/EIS_Chapter_2_Virtual_Data_Integration.pdf